# vuejs, how to bind dynamic class within a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

In Vuejs, I would like to set an "active" class on my nav. The nav is built in a v-for loop like this:

```
<li v-for="item in arrNav" v-bind:class="{'active' : item.id }">
    <a v-link="{ path: item.id }">{{ item.title}}</a>
</li>
```

here's the data:

```
arrNav: [{
    'title': 'Home',
    'id': 'home'
  },
  {
    'title': 'About',
    'id': 'about'
  },
  {
    'title': 'Contact',
    'id': 'contact'
  }]
```

This is setting an "active" class on every li. I assume this is because item.id is returning true because it's a string. Is there a way to evaluate item.id to its variable name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a more elegant to do it, as `vue-router` provides this functionality by default. If you want to give a class to the parent item of the navigation element, you can use `v-link-active`:

```
<li v-for="item in arrNav" v-link-active>
    <a v-link="{ path: item.id }">{{ item.title}}</a>
</li>
```

That will give the `li` item a `v-link-active` class. Take a look at this page on the `vue-router` documentation.